# Android ListViews in a fragment to open singleItem in another fragment onClickListener.

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListView in a Fragment "**FollowListFragment.class**". If i click on any of the listView item. It should take me to another Fragment "**KeywordFragment.class**" displaying details of the clicked item.

Below is the onClickListener of **ListViewAdapter.class**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, KeywordFragment.class);
                intent.putExtra("keyword_id", resultp.get(FollowListFragment.KWID));
                intent.putExtra("keyword", resultp.get(FollowListFragment.KW));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
```

This is the Target Fragment **KeywordFragment.class** where i want the details of the clicked item to be displayed.

```
public class KeywordFragment extends Fragment {
        String kwid,kw;

        public KeywordFragment(){}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keyword, container, false);
            Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
            kwid = i.getStringExtra("keyword_id");
            kw = i.getStringExtra("keyword");
            TextView kwtitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.kw);
            kwtitle.setText(kw);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

when i run the app, if i click the List item, App crashes.
What goes wrong and can be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`KeywordFragment` **is not an Activity**. Do the transition for a Fragment and pass your stuff via `arguments`:

```
 temView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            resultp = data.get(position);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            KeywordFragment keywordFragment = new KeywordFragment();
            bundle.putString("keyword_id", resultp.get(FollowListFragment.KWID));
            bundle.putString("keyword", resultp.get(FollowListFragment.KW));
            keywordFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_container,keywordFragment,null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Retrieve the values later with:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keyword, container, false);
        Bundle i = getArguments();
        kwid = i.getString("keyword_id");
        kw = i.getString("keyword");
        TextView kwtitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.kw);
        kwtitle.setText(kw);

        return rootView;
    }
```

As @user370305 pointed, check the docs for better understanding.

Comment: can you please focus on these 2 lines?
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = **getSupportFragmentManager()**.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.**your_container**,keywordFragment,null); 
i am getting error for getSupportFragmentManager as cannot resolve. and what is the container supposed to be?

Comment: Okay, I'm assuming you are inside a `FragmentActivity`. Is that correct?

Comment: onclicklistener is inside the ListViewAdapter that extends baseadapter.

Comment: now my ListViewAdapter implements FragmentActivity.
please tell me what is **your_container** in FragmentTranscaction.replace(R.id.your_container). i am getting error over there

Comment: No.....wait. Think about how you show your first fragment `FollowListFragment.class`. You're going to do the same there, only passing the arguments.

Comment: **FollowListFragment.class** gets and sets JSON objects to an array and passes to **ListViewAdapter.Class** and is responsible to Show the Listview with Items populated in it.
now when i click on any Item from the list i want to display it in to the **KeywordFragment.class** .
the First part of the code you corrected lies inside the **ListViewAdapter.class** that extends baseadapter